# Using AttachTo with a Contained EntitySet

Tags: c#, odata, wcf-data-services, asp.net-web-api-odata, wcf-data-services-client

I have some classes defined as below:

```
public class Table
{

    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Contained]
    public IList<TableEntity> Entities { get; set; }
}

public class TableEntity
{
    [Key]
    public string Partition { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use AttachTo to add an object to the DataServiceContext without querying for it first. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by doing

```
context.AttachTo("Tables(\'TableName\')/Entities", tableEntityInstance);
```

Not very elegant, but it works.